# R markdown Cross-reference

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, cross-reference

I have pdf file generated in R markdown, I have the page for table of content, which involves the names of headings and I want to cross reference. Could you please give me some suggestions how to do?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have `bookdown` installed and is using one of `bookdown` output formats (probably you want `bookdown::pdf_document2` instead of `pdf_document`).

Add `{#id}` to your section headings, where `id` is an unique identifier that can be anything you want.

Then use `\@ref(id)` in your text body to make a reference to that section number.

Small example:

```
---
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---

# Section A {#sectiona}

Lorem ipsum

# Section B

Lorem ipsum, see section \@ref(sectiona)
```

See more in https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cross-ref.html and https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/cross-references.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did it and I have added table of content, but the problem is that it is on the same page as title and I wish it would be on the second page of my document. Could you please give  me any advice how to deal with it?

Comment: That's because the default LaTeX document class (article) does not have a separate title page, but you can circumvent that by adding `classoption: titlepage` to your YAML preamble or changing the class to something else like adding `documentclass: report`. I suggest you just add the classoption, because changing documentclass will change more settings of your document than just the titlepage.